# cashing 401(k) including company match

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement-plan

If I cash out my 401(k) account with my previous employer, will I be able to take both my contribution and the company match at the same time ?
I assume I will pay 40% of tax (penalty + tax) on both my contribution and company match.

Comment: Are you 100% vested in all contributions?

Comment: Yes..but I have decided not to go ahead with withdrawal

Answer (score 26):

If you are vested, then the money is all yours. Tax withheld will be 20%, which is standard, but at tax time you'll owe the difference, the 10% penalty plus your marginal rate, 25% most likely.

More than that, it's our job to talk you out of this. Why not roll it to the new company 401(k) or to an IRA?

Let me add a thought - including state taxes, say you clear 60%. Instead, you transfer to the new 401(k) and borrow 50%. You pay it back over time, and instead of trashing your retirement savings, you simply have a low interest loan. To yourself.

Comment: I must STRONGLY emphasize Joe's point *it's our job to talk you out of this.*  In my 20's I once cashed out a few thousand dollars of my 401k to take a vacation.  **A VACATION!!**  Been regretting that for years!  On top of the ridiculous taxes and penalties I paid to do that, I lost tens (maybe hundreds?) of thousands of dollars in compound interest, because I made that mistake so early in my career.  Unless you are about to lose your house, or similar dire emergency, **I strongly urge you to reconsider.**

Comment: Thank you , I have decided not to touch that money ...

Comment: Excellent! Glad you can learn from our mistakes. I hope you'll visit again.